# Regexp boundary and string 'c#'

Tags: php, regex

Just curious to know. I noticed that my regexp can't find string 'C#' when using it with '\b'

```
if (preg_match('@\bC#\b@i', $userSkills)) {...
```

However if I remove '\b' it manages to find string.

Does anybody know what might be the problem here ?

String to find matches:

```
Unified Communications Design Specialist ~$~ Windows 95 or 98 ~$~ Windows 2000 
or XP ~$~ Linux ~$~ Visual Basic ~$~ ASP Net ~$~ C# ~$~ Contact Center Design 
Specialist ~$~ Internet Programming ~$~ Object oriented programming ~$~ 
Databases ~$~ Unified Commucations ~$~ Contact Center Solutions ~$~
Junior Developer ~$~ Solutions Engineer
```

Comment: Which one did you use in the regex?`\b` or `/b`?

Comment: I posted the string in which I am trying to find matches. It works with all strings except c# as far as I noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `#` is no word character. I marked the word boundaries in your string around "`C#`" with <kbd>|</kbd>:

```
|ASP| |Net| ~$~ |C|# ~$~ |Contact|
```

You see, between "`#`" and "" there is no boundary, so `\b` does not match.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question was, *why* `\b` doesn't  match, I explained it.

Comment: So any workarounds for this case except str_replace('#',' sharp',$var) ?

Comment: you could use `[\s^](C#)[\s$]`, so that before or after "C#" either whitespaces or "begin"/"end" are matched. Of course the whole pattern then matches "C#" *including* those whitespaces, therefore the subpattern parentheses.

Comment: No it won't do, i am doing this in a loop and need to match all sorts of keywords but thanks for your effort

Comment: I don't see why this is a reason against it.

Comment: Yea you are right, actually I can use this. I thought it would be a problem because of the spaces.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) is `\b` not `/b` for word boundaries.

```
if (preg_match('@\bC#\b@i', $userSkills)) {...
```

Comment: sorry made a mistake in my question, I edited it now but the problem is still there

Comment: A downvote for an answer that was 100% correct before the OP completely changed the question? Pretty ridiculous...

Comment: Well you answer was not correct regardless of slashes/backslashes...seems there is different kind of issue here

Comment: You changed the entire question - My answer answered the original question you asked.

Comment: That is simply != true. Lock. Now if you can help welcome if not find some other question where you can help I will upvote you if that makes you happy.

Comment: No thanks. I see the problem, but fail to see the justification for getting penalized for a mistake you made, so I'll leave it up for somebody else to figure out. Have a great day.